# Python urllib.urlopen IOError using VPN

Tags: python, python-2.7, http, urllib, ioerror

I am trying to access a website called scopus.com . What I want to do is to search an author in it and get his number of publications, h-index, etc. 
This website cannot be accessed if you are not on a university wifi network (I use VPN whenever I want to access it from home).

Here is the code:

```
import urllib

first_name = "John"
last_name = "Smith"

new_url = "http://www.scopus.com/results/authorNamesList.url?sort=\
count-f&src=al&sid=66892931B99391BF99AFADC3006D1357.WXhD7YyTQ6A7Pvk9AlA%3a50\
&sot=al&sdt=al&sl=47&s=AUTH--LAST--NAME%28" + last_name + \
"%29+AND+AUTH--FIRST%28" + first_name + "%29&st1=" + last_name + "&st2=" + first_name +\
"&orcidId=&selectionPageSearch=anl&reselectAuthor=false&activeFlag=false&showDocument=\
false&resultsPerPage=20&offset=1&jtp=false&currentPage=1&previousSelectionCount=\
0&tooManySelections=false&previousResultCount=0&authSubject=LFSC&authSubject=\
HLSC&authSubject=PHSC&authSubject=SOSC&exactAuthorSearch=false&showFullList=\
false&authorPreferredName=&origin=searchauthorlookup&affiliationId=&txGid=\
66892931B99391BF99AFADC3006D1357.WXhD7YyTQ6A7Pvk9AlA%3a5"

page_source = urllib.urlopen(new_url).read()

print page_source
```

No matter what I do I always get this error:

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 386, in http_error_default
raise IOError, ('http error', errcode, errmsg, headers)

IOError: ('http error', 401, 'Unauthorized', <httplib.HTTPMessage instance at 0x102c85a28>)
```

I have spent some time on this forum and I think I have tried everything I could find (including pretending to access the website as Opera). Is there anyway that I can do this or should I just give it up and do this 700 times manually?

Thank you everyone for your help in advance

Answer (score 1):

This is not related to your VPN. The main problem is you are trying to get a page which you must have a valid session (which is present on the browser's request-response cicle). Your options:

- Use [Mechanize](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mechanize/)
- Use [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)

But in any case I encorage you to use the API for this kind of problems: [Elsevier API](http://dev.elsevier.com/about.html).

Comment: I was unaware of Elsevier... this really appears the right way to handle this one, @py_coder1371 (ie. my answer's a bit more general).

Answer (score 0):

Really simply, a [401 Error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error) means that you are unauthorized (and generally, must have a login to access the site). That also being said, what you are doing is [expressly prohibited based on their robots.txt file](http://www.scopus.com/robots.txt), so I'd advise you to *not persist*.

That being said, if you were to continue being interested in crawling other websites, I'd say you should take a look at the [Python Requests Module](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/), as well as [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).